# Specifying "any subclass" in a C# type constraint rather than "one particular subclass"

Tags: c#, polyvariadic

If I would like to write a method that takes a variable number of "TDerived" where TDerived is *any* subclass of a class "Base", is there any way to do this?

The following code only works with a single specific specified subclass:

```
void doStuff<TDerived>(params TDerived[] args) where TDerived : Base
{
    //stuff
}
```

ie if I have

```
class Super { }
class Sub0 : Super { }
class Sub1 : Super { }
```

then I cannot do

```
Sub0 s0 = new Sub0();
Sub1 s1 = new Sub1();
doStuff(s0, s1);
```

since I get "best overloaded match... has some invalid arguments".

Regardless of how the compiler handles the type constraints and variadic functions, this seems (as far as I can tell) completely type-safe. I know I could cast, but if this is type safe why not allow it?

EDIT:

Perhaps a more convincing example:

```
void doStuff<TDerived>(params SomeReadOnlyCollection<TDerived>[] args) where TDerived : Base
{
    foreach(var list in args)
    {
        foreach(TDerived thing in list)
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just specify the Base type implicitly when you call the function: doStuff<Super>(s0, s1);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TDerived` needs to be able to resolve to a single type. In your example, the only type it *could* resolve to would be `Super`, but the compiler is not going to make that leap. You can make that leap *for* the compiler.

```
doStuff(new Super[] { s0, s1 });
doStuff<Super>(s0, s1);
```

---

**Regarding your update**, consider (instead of a generic method) defining a method accepting `IEnumerable<ISuper>`, which will support derived types because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant (as of .NET 4). `IEnumerable<T>` is also inherently readonly and forward-only, perfect if you have a `foreach` loop. Full working example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sub0s = new Sub0[] { new Sub0() };
        var sub1s = new List<Sub1> { new Sub1() };
        doStuff(sub0s, sub1s);
    }

    static void doStuff(params IEnumerable<ISuper>[] args)
    {
        foreach (var sequence in args)
        {
            foreach (var obj in sequence)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType());
                // you have the ability to invoke any method or access 
                // any property defined on ISuper
            }
        }
    } 
}

interface ISuper { }
class Super : ISuper { }
class Sub0 : Super { }
class Sub1 : Super { }
```

`IEnumerable<T>` is implemented by BCL collections since .NET 2.0, including `T[]`, `List<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, you are actually telling the compiler that all arguments to `doStuff` must be of the same type at compile time, and that this type has to be inherited from `Base`. If you want to allow the arguments to be of different types, then just don't use generics:

```
void doStuff(params Base[] args)
{}
```

**EDIT**

The same applies with your new example - instead of a specific `SomeReadOnlyCollection` you can use `IEnumerable`, as it is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx):

```
void doStuff(params IEnumerable<Base>[] args)
{
    foreach (var list in args)
    {
        foreach (var thing in list)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: added a more complicated example

Answer (score 0):

Well you could most certainly change

```
Sub0 s0 = new Sub0();
Sub1 s1 = new Sub1();
```

To

```
Super s0 = new Sub0();
Super s1 = new Sub1();
```

and then it would work if Super is TDerived.

I may be misunderstanding you, but the only way to make a method take any subclass of a base class is to declare the method to take a reference to the base type.

Answer (score 0):

One other alternative you could use is to simply  specify the generic parameter explicitly. For example:

```
var s0 = new Sub0();
var s1 = new Sub1();

doStuff<Super>(s0, s1);
```

You should be able to apply the same principle on the case with `SomeReadOnlyCollection`, as long as it is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). For example, `IEnumerable` is such a collection:

```
static void doStuff2<TDerived>(params IEnumerable<TDerived>[] args) where TDerived : Super {
    // ...
}

// ...

var l0 = new List<Sub0>();
var l1 = new List<Sub1>();

doStuff2<Super>(l0, l1);
```